# Draw arrows between flexbox items, even on different rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, arrows

I want to draw a line between flex items, even then they go to different rows, I don't know where to start, I know you can draw svg between divs, but I wonder how this would work with resizing, is even possible:

[image: Preview]

Comment: As SO is not a code writing service, you need to provide a initial working code snippet.

Comment: You can make your border by http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/s3vd2hny/. To make responsive, you can play with some jQuery. Add any class after fetching last element of each row if next element is available. You can also add any class to next row's first element if needed.